# Could not find table 'tags_travels' rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem, I want to create an hashtags system, but when I run my code, and when I want to create a travel that contain hashtags I have this error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in TravelsController#create
Could not find table 'tags_travels'
```

Here is my travel.rb

```
class Travel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  #after / before create
  after_create do
    travel = Travel.find_by(id: self.id)
    sh = self.hashtags.scan(/#\w+/)
    sh.uniq.map do |s|
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(name: s.downcase.delete('#'))
      travel.tags << tag
    end
  end

  before_update do
    travel = Travel.find_by(id: self.id)
    travel.tags.clear
    sh = self.hashtags.scan(/#\w+/)
    sh.uniq.map do |s|
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(name: s.downcase.delete('#'))
      travel.tags << tag
    end
  end
end
```

my tag.rb

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :travels
end
```

the schema.rb file (just table concerned) :

```
 create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "topics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "text"
    t.string   "end_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end

  create_table "travels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "trip_type"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "hashtags"
  end

  create_table "travels_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "travel_id"
    t.integer "tag_id"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_travels_tags_on_tag_id"
    t.index

 ["travel_id"], name: "index_travels_tags_on_travel_id"
  end
```

Someone has a solution ? Thank !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails looks for join tables in a specific syntax. Its trying to find `tags_travles` but uouve created it with `travels_tags`.

Change your model associations to specify the join table.

`has_and_belongs_to_many :travels,  :join_table => :travels_tags`

And

`has_and_belongs_to_many :tags,  :join_table => :travels_tags`

Heres some info from the docs to help explain the defsult behaviour for join table naming.

"By default, the name of the join table comes from the union of the first two arguments provided to create_join_table, in alphabetical order."

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table